# Show that the direct product of a family indexed by a partition of set must have one-one mapping

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So this is an exercise I stumbled upon in an introductory book to the field of topology, in a preface chapter that discusses arbitrary products and it is phrased exactly as follows:

> Let {$X_\alpha$}$_{\alpha\in I}$ be an indexed family of sets
> and let $I = I_1{\cup}I_2$, where $I_1{\cap}I_2 = \emptyset$.
> Show that there is a one-one mapping between $(\prod_{{\alpha}{\in}I_1}X_\alpha) \times (\prod_{{\alpha}{\in}I_2}X_\alpha)$ onto $\prod_{{\alpha}{\in}I}X_\alpha$.

Now, I am not really sure where to begin with this one and I maybe misunderstanding some basic concept but I don't see how does the indexing set affects the product of the actual family it indexes.

Any directions, guidance or hints regarding this exercise will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $\prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$ is set of functions $I \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha$ s.t. image of $\alpha \in I$ is in $X_\alpha$.

Define function $F: \prod_{\alpha \in I} X_\alpha \to (\prod_{\alpha \in I_1} X_\alpha) \times (\prod_{\alpha \in I_2} X_\alpha)$ by rule $F(f) = \langle f|_{I_1}, f|_{I_2}\rangle$ - restriction of $f$ to $I_1$ and $I_2$.

$F$ is injection: if $f_1(\alpha) \neq f_2(\alpha)$ then either $\alpha \in I_1$ and $f_1|_{I_1}(\alpha) \neq f_2|_{I_1}(\alpha)$, or $\alpha \in I_2$ and $f_1|_{I_2}(\alpha) \neq f_2|_{I_2}(\alpha)$.
In both cases, $\langle f_2|_{I_1}, f_2|_{I_2}\rangle \neq \langle f_2|_{I_1}, f_2|_{I_2}\rangle$.

$F$ is also surjection: preimage of pair $\langle g, h\rangle$ is function $f$ defined by $$f(\alpha) = \begin{cases} g(\alpha), \alpha \in I_1\\ h(\alpha), \alpha \in I_2\end{cases}$$

Thus $F$ is one-one mapping.